# Compress Files in Multiple Directories

Tags: file, directory, compression

I would like to compress the files in multiple directories. For some reason, it only compress the first directory (/Sanbox/logs1) but not the rest of the other directories ("/Sanbox/logs2" "/Sanbox/logs3" "/Sanbox/logs4" ). Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILES=( "/Sanbox/logs1" "/Sanbox/logs2" "/Sanbox/logs3" "/Sanbox/logs4" )

for file in ${LOG_FILES[file]}/* ; do
    gzip "${file}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that I suggest to change in your script.
First one is the way, how you are using array in a for-loop. 
Try to iterate using

```
for file in ${LOG_FILES[@]}; do
    # code that creates archives
done
```

Using "@" or "*" as the index number tells that whole array should be used in the for-loop.

Second thing is the way how you are creating directory path, that is used to create archive. Try to add "/*" inside of the for loop body, not in the line with a for-do.

Something like this should do the trick.

```
LOG_FILES=( "/Sanbox/logs1" "/Sanbox/logs2" "/Sanbox/logs3" "/Sanbox/logs4" )

for file in ${LOG_FILES[@]}; do
    gzip "${file}"/*; 
done
```

For more info about using arrayis in Bash, you can check [Bash Begginers Guide: Array variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html)